# Have different users' records in one table - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I was just wondering if you could help with a certain database dilemma.

My friend and I are working on a database solution for small businesses to use to log their sales, customers, products etc.

So for starters it's your run of the mill basic database with customer, sales, product tables etc! It will eventually get more complex as development goes into it.

However, we were debating how we should go about the solution. So all our clients will stay on 1 database for starters and expand as necessary, now I made the argument that we should have each company/client as a different database user that way we have tables separated.

My friend made the argument that this will require extra work to setup all the other tables for each client, and the users etc. etc. When in the end they'd all use most of the tables with the same structure. Eg. Sales table, customer table etc.

He wants to keep them under ONE database user, and hide records from them on the application layer, which will mean less work for us setting up tables etc, and we can easily disable certain solution features and whatnot depending on the users' subscription level and so on and so forth.

Of course I think that's a clunky way of doing it, lots of things can go wrong (different users seeing each others' data and whatnot), besides the crazy amount of records each table will have as the amount of users AND data ramp up.

What do you think is a good way to go on about this? We're just really thinking ahead, but don't have much experience and so I thought it would be worthwhile to reach out to someone who has had some first-hand experience with these sorts of things.

Thanks in advance!

-Andrew

Comment: Read up on "multi-tenancy"

Comment: Found a great microsoft documentation on multi-tenancy. Thank you so much @Richard. This is exactly what we needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx
Found this by searching up multi-tenancy as suggested by @Richard.
Thanks for your help, this is exactly what we needed to know!